# Unit test for uC/OS - II

Tags: unit-testing, testing, operating-system, embedded, ucos

I am a graduate student and I am trying to propose a project for a advanced testing course.

Since I am a embedded guy, I do want to test something challenging related to embedded systems.

uC/OS-II is an very nice open source light-weighted OS for embedded systems. So I want to propose the testing for it for my course project.

But I don't know the feasibility of testing uC/OS. Is it doable?
I am using Blackfin and SHARC (are from Analog Devices) now and they are compatible with uC/OS (said on the uC/OS website).
In terms of testing tools, I think CUnit might work. Also we have a unit testing tool call EmbeddedUnit, which runs on VDSP (development environment for Analog Devices processors).
I have no experience with uC/OS, but my understanding is we should compile it and then include the .obj files and the header files into the project then we can use and test the functions in uC/OS.

Am I right?

Comment: uCOS is a nice small OS that you can get to run in almost any system.  But it's not clear what you are trying to test.  Are you wanting to test the OS itself?  If so, which aspects: scheduling, timers, priorities, queues, semaphores?  Or are you trying to have a framework to test application code that runs on uCOS?

Comment: Strictly speaking, uCOS-II isn't open source (at least last time I checked). The source is freely available for educational purposes, but commercial use requires a paid license from Micrium. That might not be an issue for your use, but might be for some readers.

Answer (score 2):

Is it doable?  Yes it is.  We had a project that needed to be portable to many different environments uCos-II, Linux and VxWorks. In order to do that we wrote as simple abstraction layer that gave us a common API on all platforms to the OS features we chose to have enabled.  We then wrote a Unit Test to test the abstraction layer, and had a unit test case for each OS feature we wanted to test (Msg Queues, Semaphores, Event Flags etc). We used that to verify our abstraction layer was functional and working on all 3 host environments.

uCos-II is delivered as very clean c-code that can easily be used in any number of tools such as code coverage etc.

Good luck.